# Sending data in Android WiFi Direct service discovery instead of connecting

Tags: android, wifi-direct

Following the documentation here:

http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd-wifi-direct.html

It appears to be possible to broadcast data to all nearby devices that have WiFi Direct without establishing a connection by just putting the data in a WifiP2pDnsSdServiceInfo object. This works for my purposes as I'm attempting to establish a simple P2P messaging app amongst multiple nearby devices. However it seems like a misuse of the API as this is intended to carry information to setup a connection and advertise a service. My questions are:

- What are the pros and cons of sending data this way (please ignore security)?
- Will there be delays in messages being sent/received.
- What will the impact on battery life be like?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- The key/value pairs you pass into `WifiP2pDnsSdServiceInfo` object are going to be encapsulated into DNS multicast messages, as specified in [**DNS-Based Service Discovery**](http://files.dns-sd.org/draft-cheshire-dnsext-dns-sd.txt).
- Multicast traffic on WiFi is especially expensive, so it is not recommended to use this for messaging. Only for critical things like service discovery.
- Depending on implementation (android), the under framework may pool all service discovery records/responses, before it calls your callbacks. This can add significant (even unpredictable) delay for your simple P2P messaging.
- This is basically a DNS messaging, so your "messages" may be cached locally. DNS queries could also try mid-level optimizations like pooling, retries, query filtering, prioritization etc.
- There is no reliability guarantee so your messages may be lost.
- Multicast traffic, which is used here, can result in significant [battery drain on android, see here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.MulticastLock.html)

Comment: Can you comment on the performance (speed-wise) and battery usage of setting up and maintaining a connection with another device?

Comment: @ajnatural with `WifiP2pDnsSdServiceInfo` there is no connection setup, it is zero configuration, multicast broadcast talk/listen. Performance will be unreliable as i mentioned in answer, and batter drain heavy due to it having to do broadcast. If are referring to regular WiFi P2P connection, once you discovered and established a connection, WiFi P2P will be in similar speedy/power-efficient as regular wifi connection.