# Android Wi-Fi Direct send data before connection

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifi-direct, service-discovery, wifip2p

I'm developing an app which uses Wi-Fi direct to connect devices. I read how to connect, send data and disconnect the devices here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html. Now, I'd like to send some data BEFORE the connection, in order to show some informations about the device. I've Googled this but the only answer I've found is this: [Sending data in Android WiFi Direct service discovery instead of connecting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26367191/sending-data-in-android-wifi-direct-service-discovery-instead-of-connecting), which uses services discovery.

Is there a way I can send data before the pairing process without using the service discovery? If I can't, can you explain what is the difference between service discovery and normal Wi-Fi P2P?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you have some other medium you can rely on (e.g. some sort of back-end you can use to exchange information), you will need `Service Discovery`.

I have already written a few answers regarding `WifiP2p` and `Service Discovery`, and I suggest you take a look at them first. The last one should probably interest you the most.

1. [Why is discovering peers for Android WifiDirect so unreliable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27476711/1993204)
2. [Wi-fi P2P. Inform all peers available of some event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29769877/1993204)
3. [**Wifi P2P service discovery works intermittently**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31641302/1993204)

---

To answer your question about the difference between `WifiP2p` and `ServiceDiscovery`, let me use a small analogy:

> Imagine you're at the airport, you've just landed in a foreign
>   country. You're leaving the duty-free zone and you see all the people
>   that are waiting for people who have landed at the airport just like
>   you did. You need to find your taxi driver. You know he should be
>   waiting for you with a small piece of paper with your name on it. You
>   can see many guys like that, every single one of them is holding a
>   piece of paper with a name on it. You need to read through many of
>   them until you find the one with yours. But you don't have to talk to
>   all those people. You will talk only to your taxi driver, and you will
>   probably tell much more than just your name.

Now let me explain... Every single person holding a piece of paper represents a `Broadcasted Service`. Every `broadcasted service` can carry a small piece of information (a person name). The space for the information is very limited (you can't write much on the paper), and is "relatively permanent" (it takes a bit to change it). When you were searching for the right person, you were performing a `Service Discovery`. You did not have to talk to all those people to read the names on those pieces of papers - you didn't have to connect to them (WiFiP2p-wise). When you found the one you were interested in, you talked to the man - you established a WiFiP2p connection. Now you can talk to him as much as you want - you can pass as much data as you want through the connection.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer was clear and really well made. Unfortunately, I was thinking to send data like an image and some other infos but it seems that's not possible. I will look into this a little bit more to see how much data I can put into the broadcast. Thank you, +1 and accepted.

Comment: Yep you probably won't be able to send an image. Maybe you could broadcast an url to the image (I don't remember the limit for the broadcasted message)